# Flatpickr change minDate maxDate on the fly

Tags: javascript, flatpickr

Hi I'm trying to replace the *datetimepicker* with *flatpickr* but I can't handle this situation.
Not wishing to use the Range plugin of flatpickr I would like to be able to change the minDate or maxDate of an instance using the onChange event.
Unfortunately I found little information about this passage on the guides

```
 flatpickr('#start_time', {
    locale: 'it',
    enableTime: true,
    plugins: [
      new confirmDate({
        confirmIcon: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>",
        confirmText: '',
        showAlways: true,
      }),
    ],
    showAlways: false,
    theme: 'airbnb',
    time_24hr: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'F j, Y H:i',
    dateFormat: 'Z',
    weekNumbers: true,
    maxDate: $('#end_time').attr('value'),
    onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    // Change #end_time minDate
    },
  });

  flatpickr('#end_time', {
    locale: 'it',
    enableTime: true,
    plugins: [
      new confirmDate({
        confirmIcon: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>",
        confirmText: '',
        showAlways: true,
      }),
    ],
    showAlways: false,
    theme: 'airbnb',
    time_24hr: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'F j, Y H:i',
    dateFormat: 'Z',
    weekNumbers: true,
    minDate: $('#start_time').attr('value'),
    onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    // Change #start_time maxDate
    },
  });
```

I tried to play with `$('#start_time')[0]._flatpickr.config._maxDate` but without success

Thanks ;)

Comment: why tag _ruby-on-rails_?

Comment: the file is a `.js.erb` but I noticed now that there is no rails code. I remove it ;)

Answer (score 7):

Solved in this way

```
let startpicker = flatpickr('#start_time', {
    locale: 'it',
    enableTime: true,
    plugins: [
      new confirmDate({
        confirmIcon: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>",
        confirmText: '',
        showAlways: true,
      }),
    ],
    showAlways: false,
    theme: 'airbnb',
    time_24hr: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'F j, Y H:i',
    dateFormat: 'Z',
    weekNumbers: true,
    maxDate: $('#end_time').attr('value'),
    onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      endpicker.set('minDate', dateStr);
    },
  });

  let endpicker = flatpickr('#end_time', {
    locale: 'it',
    enableTime: true,
    plugins: [
      new confirmDate({
        confirmIcon: "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>",
        confirmText: '',
        showAlways: true,
      }),
    ],
    showAlways: false,
    theme: 'airbnb',
    time_24hr: true,
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'F j, Y H:i',
    dateFormat: 'Z',
    weekNumbers: true,
    minDate: $('#start_time').attr('value'),
    onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      startpicker.set('maxDate', dateStr);
    },
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved minutes of my life <3